# Surpass JSON text is not properly formatted when updating corrupted JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have an SQL table that contains a JSON column that contains corrupted entries (missing double quotes).
I was trying to delete those entries by using JSON_Modify but it gives me this error "JSON text is not properly formatted". Is there a way to work around this error?

My query :

> ```
> Update table
> Set json_col = JSON_MODIFY(json_col , '$.date', null)
> ```

Thank you in advance,

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: No JSON functions will work if the JSON isn't valid. How about you actually give us an example of invalid JSON that you are trying to fix

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

**SQL**

```
Update table
Set json_col = null
WHERE ISJSON(json_col) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what I am looking for is a way to update my corrupted json entries and not to check if they are json valid.

Comment: Please update your question with ##1-4